# Removing whitespaces in a CSV file

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, rake-task

I have a string with extra whitespace:

```
First,Last,Email  ,Mobile Phone ,Company,Title  ,Street,City,State,Zip,Country, Birthday,Gender ,Contact Type
```

I want to parse this line and remove the whitespaces.

My code looks like:

```
namespace :db do
task :populate_contacts_csv => :environment do

require 'csv'

csv_text = File.read('file_upload_example.csv')
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      puts "First Name: #{row['First']} \nLast Name: #{row['Last']} \nEmail: #{row['Email']}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `strip` your hash first:

```
csv.each do |unstriped_row|
  row = {}
  unstriped_row.each{|k, v| row[k.strip] = v.strip}
  puts "First Name: #{row['First']} \nLast Name: #{row['Last']} \nEmail: #{row['Email']}"
end
```

Edited to strip hash keys too

Comment: This won't work. The header for "Email" isn't "Email" causing the code to not find a value.

Answer (score 68):

```
@prices = CSV.parse(IO.read('prices.csv'), :headers=>true, 
   :header_converters=> lambda {|f| f.strip},
   :converters=> lambda {|f| f ? f.strip : nil})
```

The nil test is added to the row but not header converters assuming that the headers are never nil, while the data might be, and nil doesn't have a strip method. I'm really surprised that, AFAIK, :strip is not a pre-defined converter!

Comment: Instead of using syntax `lambda {|f| f.strip}`, you can use the `->` syntax like: `->(f) {f.strip}`

Comment: This one was the solution for my problem, also works on CSV.new, not just CSV.parse.

Comment: also from ruby 2.3, `->(f) { f&.strip }`

Answer (score 4):

CSV supports "converters" for the [headers](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-header_convert) and [fields](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-convert), which let you get inside the data before it's passed to your `each` loop.

Writing a sample CSV file:

```
csv = "First,Last,Email  ,Mobile Phone ,Company,Title  ,Street,City,State,Zip,Country, Birthday,Gender ,Contact Type
first,last,email  ,mobile phone ,company,title  ,street,city,state,zip,country, birthday,gender ,contact type
"
File.write('file_upload_example.csv', csv)
```

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'csv'
csv = CSV.open('file_upload_example.csv', :headers => true)
[:convert, :header_convert].each { |c| csv.send(c) { |f| f.strip } }

csv.each do |row|
  puts "First Name: #{row['First']} \nLast Name: #{row['Last']} \nEmail: #{row['Email']}"
end
```

Which outputs:

```
First Name: 'first'
Last Name: 'last'
Email: 'email'
```

The converters simply strip leading and trailing whitespace from each header and each field as they're read from the file.

Also, as a programming design choice, don't read your file into memory using:

```
csv_text = File.read('file_upload_example.csv')
```

Then parse it:

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
```

Then loop over it:

```
csv.each do |row|
```

Ruby's IO system supports "enumerating" over a file, line by line. Once my code does `CSV.open` the file is readable and the `each` reads each line. The entire file doesn't need to be in memory at once, which isn't scalable (though on new machines it's becoming a lot more reasonable), and, if you test, you'll find that reading a file using `each` is extremely fast, probably equally fast as reading it, parsing it then iterating over the parsed file.