# ruby: read cvs with quotes given a column name

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a following csv:

```
"id","title"
1070,"\"stern\" Abo"
1071,"stern_de"
```

To read only the first column I can do following:

```
CSV.foreach(a, :headers => true, :quote_char => "'") do |row| b.push(row[0]) end
```

However, I want to address the column rather by column name than by index.

The above command return me an array `b` filled with nils.

```
CSV.foreach(a, :headers => true, :quote_char => "'") do |row| b.push(row['title']) end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is occurring because you have "cheated" in how you are parsing the escaped quotation marks in the CSV file, by use of `:quote_char => "'"`. The quote character is *not* `'`, it is still just the default of `"`!

Without fixing this mistake, you *could* access each column by its header, by including the extra quotation mark that you've inadvertently included:

```
CSV.foreach(a, :headers => true, :quote_char => "'") do |row|
  row['"title"']
end
```

However, as outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534628/1954610), a better solution is to first convert the data into a valid *ruby* CSV structure and then access it as normal - i.e. something like:

```
text = File.read('your-input-file.csv').gsub(/\\"/,'""')
CSV.parse(text, headers: true) do |row|
  b.push(row['title'])
end
```

Comment: How big are the files you're dealing with? Are you actually likely to hit this limit? If so, you can - as the linked answer suggests - just modify the code to read the file one line at a time.